# visual studio integrated mode

Tags: visual-studio

Hi
Does anyone know of an app built using( or showcasing the use of) Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Integrated)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NuGet:  http://nuget.codeplex.com